# Pass searchbox text as query param

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript.

When user enters any text or if he clicks on the search icon, i need to get the search text value and pass on that value as query param and redirect it to search results page.

Issue here is , when the page got loaded it directly redirects to the search results page without entering any text. Could you please let me know what i'm doing wrong ?

```text
http://localhost:3000/search/searchresults.html?query=&filter=newsroom&site=allsite_all&ei=r1_search
```

```js
// Only run function if the newssearch search field exists
if ($('#search_banner-q_newsroom').length >= 1) {
  $("#search_banner-q_newsroom").on('keypress', setupNewsroomSearch());
}

function setupNewsroomSearch() {
  var tracking;
  if ($(".self-service-search").length > 0) {
    tracking = "&ei=r2_pt_search";
  } else {
    tracking = "&ei=r1_search";
  }
  redirectToSearchPage($("#search_banner-q_newsroom").val(), "newsroom", "site_all", tracking);
}
```

```html
<form class="search_box_wrapper">
  <div class="search-box">
    <input type="text" id="search_banner-q_newsroom" aria-label="Search" name="query" placeholder="Search" />
    <i class="icon-magnifying-glass search_desktop-newsroom-submit"></i>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're calling the `setupNewsroomSearch()` function immediately on load and providing it's return value to the `keypress` handler. Instead you need to give the event handler the *reference* of the function, like this:

```
$("#search_banner-q_newsroom").on('keypress', setupNewsroomSearch); // Note: () removed
```

Also note that the `if` statement is redundant. jQuery is tolerant of calling functions on jQuery objects which matched no elements. Here's a tidied version of your JS logic:

```
$("#search_banner-q_newsroom").on('keypress', setupNewsroomSearch);

function setupNewsroomSearch() {
  var tracking = $(".self-service-search").length > 0 ? '&ei=r2_pt_search' : '&ei=r1_search';
  redirectToSearchPage($(this).val(), 'newsroom', 'site_all', tracking);
}
```

Comment: it worked Thanks!! But i need to call the same function when user clicks on the search icon i've done like this `$("#search_banner-q_newsroom").on('keyenter', setupNewsroomSearch);
$(".search_desktop-newsroom-submit").on('click', setupNewsroomSearch)` is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: Nope - that's the perfect way to do it

Comment: I'm facing another issue, When i keyin any text it immediately redirects to the search page . it should redirect only after press enter..I tried with keyenter but not working

Comment: In that case you could put the `input` in a `form` and only call your function when that form is submit. Or you could use `keyup` to detect return key presses. I'd start a new question if you have some issues.